# Why does my framer-motion content doesn't animating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I created component with documentation, but it doesn't work, help to resolve it. I need to animate children in queue by increasing delay

```
const Intro = () => {
    const navAnimation = {
        hidden: {
            y: -500,
            opacity: 0
        },
        visible: (custom: number) => ({
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            transition: {delay: custom * 0.2}
        }),
    }
return (
<div> 
    <motion.div initial={'hidden'} whileInView={'visible'}> 
        <motion.div custom={1} variants={navAnimation}>
            <p>text</p>
        </motion.div>
    <motion.div custom={2} variants={navAnimation}>
            <p>text</p>
        </motion.div>
    </motion.div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you wrap navAnimation with another motion.div?

Comment: I have many children and I want to animate them by queue, how to do it in my case ? @AliSattarzadeh

Comment: aha let me update my answer

Comment: updated my answer, let me know if it's what you are looking for

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh ,btw do you know why it's not triggering by a first render with adding instead of whileInView='visible' - animate='visible'

Comment: actually no, but as far as I know animate's value is not like initial's value it take sth like style's value and in this case I think whileInView makes sense

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I found out, it needs to be wrapped into <AnimatePresence> ... </AnimatePresence>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is from having 2 motion.div element
you problem is because navAnimation is not applied to parent element
if you simply add variants={navAnimation} to parent element, your problem will be solved

```
<motion.div initial='hidden' variants={navAnimation} whileInView='visible'> 
        <p>text</p>
</motion.div>
```

for animating children in queue you can handle it in this way :

```
       <div>
            <motion.div initial='hidden' transition={{ delay: 1 * 0.2 }} whileInView='visible' variants={navAnimation}>
              <p>text</p>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div initial='hidden' transition={{ delay: 2 * 0.2 }} whileInView='visible'  variants={navAnimation}>
              <p>text</p>
            </motion.div>
        </div>
```